# set multiple properties simultaneously via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, plinq

I'm trying to optimize the reflection utilization in my code and I was wondering
whether it's possible to set multiple properties of the object at once:

Sample usage:

```
private void SetProperties<T>(List<T> objects, List<Tuple<string, object>> propsAndValues) where T:Task
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            var propInfos = propsAndValues.ToDictionary(key => type.GetProperty(key.Item1, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty), elem => elem.Item2);

            objects.AsParallel().ForAll(obj =>
                {
                    obj.SetProps(propInfos);                                  
                });

        }
```

where

```
public static void SetProps<T>(this T obj, Dictionary<PropertyInfo, object> propInfos) where T : Task
        {
            foreach (var propInfo in propInfos)
            {
                propInfo.Key.SetValue(obj, propInfo.Value, null);
            }            
        }
```

I want SetProps extension method to be replaced by something more efficient, but haven't found anything appropriate yet.
Thanks in advance ;)

I've modified the code using the links provided in comments. The regular way is still 4 times faster. The question is whether this is the limit or there is a room for improvement?

```
class DelegateFactory
{
    public delegate void LateBoundPropertySet(object target, object value);

    public delegate void LateBoundPropertyListSet(object target, List<object> values);

    public static LateBoundPropertySet CreateSetIL(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod("Set" + property.Name, null, new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }, true);
        var gen = method.GetILGenerator();

        var sourceType = property.DeclaringType;
        var setter = property.GetSetMethod(true);

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Load input to stack
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, sourceType); // Cast to source type
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // Load value to stack
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, property.PropertyType); // Unbox the value to its proper value type
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setter); // Call the setter method
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var result = (LateBoundPropertySet)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(LateBoundPropertySet));

        return result;
    }

    public static LateBoundPropertySet CreateSet(PropertyInfo property)
    {

        var setterType = typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyType);

        var propertyWriter = typeof(PropertyWriter<,>).MakeGenericType(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyType);

        var setterDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(setterType, property.GetSetMethod());

        var writer = (IPropertyWriter)Activator.CreateInstance(propertyWriter, setterDelegate);

        return writer.SetValue;

    }

    private interface IPropertyWriter
    {
        void SetValue(object instance, object value);
    }

    private interface IPropertyListWriter
    {

        void SetValues(object instance, List<object> values);

    }

    private class PropertyWriter<TInstance, TProperty> : IPropertyWriter
    {

        private readonly Action<TInstance, TProperty> _setValueDelegate;

        public PropertyWriter(Action<TInstance, TProperty> setValueDelegate)
        {

            _setValueDelegate = setValueDelegate;

        }

        public void SetValue(object instance, object value)
        {

            _setValueDelegate((TInstance)instance, (TProperty)value);
        }

    }

}

public static void SetProps2<T>(this T obj, Dictionary<DelegateFactory.LateBoundPropertySet, object> propSetters) where T : Task
    {                        
        foreach (var propSet in propSetters)
        {
            propSet.Key.Invoke(propSet, propSet.Value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing enough reflection that this is **genuinely** a bottleneck, then dynamic code may be worth investigating. Until then - maybe [`HyperDescriptor`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) will reduce the cost; very similar code, but much cheaper.

In .NET 4.0 and above, the `Expression` API allows you to set multiple properties, but this is only really viable if you cache the delegate. The other interesting option (with the same constraint: you must cache and re-use the delegate) is `DynamicMethod`. However, all of these options are fairly advanced topics. I'm happy to advise, but do you **really** need this?

Comment: Thanks for the advices.
I'm gonna explore these topics.
It is a bottleneck in certain cases, so I'm really trying to reduce the cost of it.

Comment: @Marc Gravell when doing p.SetValue on a type that is added to the HyperDescriptor sometimes some strange errors might occur

Comment: @Omu "sometimes some strange errors might occur" has now taken pride-of-place as my favorite bug report of all time ;p

Comment: @Marc Gravell I didn't use it for a long time, but as I remember, it was when doing a SetValue which requires an implicit conversion (unboxing) like if you have a property p of type int and you do p.SetValue(obj, x) and  x is object x = 1; than I was getting some kind of overflow error

Answer (score 1):

As Marc has already told you it is better to use dynamic code to improve the performance.

You can either choose between [DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx) approach or [Delegate.CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) with GetSetMethod.

For DynamicMethod you can see an example here: [Late-Bound Invocations with DynamicMethod](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/08/05/late-bound-invocations-with-dynamicmethod.aspx)
As for CreateDelegate have a look at this question: [CreateDelegate with unknown types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490828/createdelegate-with-unknown-types)

Comment: Thanks for the useful links.
However I haven't found a way to develop the objects presented there into the correspondent lists and the performance improvement was insignificant...

Comment: @Gena as Marc has said you need to add caching to see a significant performance improvement.