# Create delegate for property acessor obtained via reflection when property type unknown

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

In .NET 2.0 (with C# 3.0), how can I create a delegate for a property accessor obtained via reflection when I don't know its type at compile time?

E.g. if I have  property of type `int`, I can do this:

```
Func<int> getter = (Func<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<int>),
    this, property.GetGetMethod(true));
Action<int> setter = (Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Action<int>),
    this, property.GetSetMethod(true));
```

but if I do not know what type the property is at compile time, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Not sure but this the following question looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773099/generating-delegate-types-dynamically-in-c

Comment: `Func<T>` is .NET 3.5.... is this a custom `Func<T>`?

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Whoops was actually playing around in a scratch project targeting the wrong platform, but it does work with a custom Func<T> in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is:

```
Delegate getter = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType), this,
    property.GetGetMethod(true));
Delegate setter = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType), this,
    property.GetSetMethod(true));
```

however, if you are doing this for performance, you are still going to come up short, since you would need to use `DynamicInvoke()`, which is *slooow*. You might want to look at meta-programming to write a wrapper that takes/returns `object`. Or look at HyperDescriptor which does this for you.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490828/createdelegate-with-unknown-types ?

Comment: @Till if you mean the accepted answer... if you don't know the type in advance, you are going to have to use `MakeGenericMethod()`; it then uses reflection to create a delegate to immediately use once and discard. Frankly, in that example, raw reflection (`GetValue()`/`SetValue()`) would have been better.

Comment: @Marc Gravel - Yes, was trying to do it for performance. I will check out HyperDescriptor when I have more time - looks amazing.

Comment: @Ergwun I can talk you through about 3 other ways of achieving similar ends if you need something lighter-weight; let me know. ILGenerator leaps to mind

Comment: @Ergwun will add something later