# Get accessors from PropertyInfo as Func<object> and Action<object> delegates

Tags: c#, reflection, linq-expressions

I need to call properties that are determined at runtime through reflection and they are called at a high frequency. So I am looking for solution with optimal performance, which mean I'd probably avoid reflection. I was thinking of storing the property accessors as Func and Action delegates in a list and then call those.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Tuple<Func<object>, Action<object>>> dataProperties =
        new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Func<object>, Action<object>>>();

private void BuildDataProperties()
{
    foreach (var keyValuePair in this.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Data"))
        .Select(
            p =>
                new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<Func<object>, Action<object>>>(
                    p.Name,
                    Tuple.Create(this.GetGetter(p), this.GetSetter(p)))))
    {
        this.dataProperties.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
    }
}
```

The question now is, how do I get the accessor delagates as Func and Action delgates for later invokation?

A naïve implementation that still uses reflection for the invocation would look like this:

```
private Func<object> GetGetter(PropertyInfo info)
{
    // 'this' is the owner of the property
    return () => info.GetValue(this);
}

private Action<object> GetSetter(PropertyInfo info)
{
    // 'this' is the owner of the property
    return v => info.SetValue(this, v);
}
```

How could I implement the above methods without refelections. Would expressions be the fastest way? I have tried using expression like this:

```
private Func<object> GetGetter(PropertyInfo info)
{
    // 'this' is the owner of the property
    return
        Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
            Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(this), info.GetGetMethod()), typeof(object)))
            .Compile();
}

private Action<object> GetSetter(PropertyInfo info)
{
    // 'this' is the owner of the property
    var method = info.GetSetMethod();
    var parameterType = method.GetParameters().First().ParameterType;
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(parameterType, "value");
    var methodCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(this), method, parameter);

    // ArgumentException: ParameterExpression of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(methodCall, parameter).Compile();
}
```

But here the last line of `GetSetter` I get the following excpetion if the type of the property is not exactly of type `System.Object`:

> ArgumentException: ParameterExpression of type 'System.Boolean' cannot
>   be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'

Comment: Your non-reflection solution is still using reflection. (`info.GetGetMethod()` and `method.GetParameters()` etc)

Comment: Just use reflection and cache the delegate it found with delegate.CreateDelegate

Comment: Do you *have* to have `Func<object>` and `Action<object>` rather than the appropriate types, e.g. `Func<bool>` and `Action<bool>`?

Comment: @Jamiec but that will only be done during inintializaiton, once the expresion is compiled, reflection is out of the way. I am storing the delegates for later invocation.

Comment: So I dont get the expression bit, maybe im not understanding but it sounds like you already have the answer - it matches the answer I posted below.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated my question to explain why I **think** that I need to have `Func<object>` and `Action<object>` rather than the appropriate types.

Comment: @JamesBarrass I was thinking of that too. I just couldn't figure out how to call `delegate.CreateDelegate`.

Comment: @bitbonk [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239833/create-delegate-for-property-acessor-obtained-via-reflection-when-property-type)

Comment: @JamesBarrass From that answer: "however, if you are doing this for performance, you are still going to come up short, since you would need to use DynamicInvoke(), which is slooow. " So I guess that is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is return the Lamda as the correct type, with `object` as the parameter, however do a conversion within the expression to the correct type before calling the setter:

```
 private Action<object> GetSetter(PropertyInfo info)
 {
     // 'this' is the owner of the property
     var method = info.GetSetMethod();
     var parameterType = method.GetParameters().First().ParameterType;

     // have the parameter itself be of type "object"
     var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");

     // but convert to the correct type before calling the setter
     var methodCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(this), method, 
                        Expression.Convert(parameter,parameterType));

     return Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(methodCall, parameter).Compile();

  }
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/HWVX33724

Comment: And I've learned a lot while investigating this question. Thanks OP!

Comment: That worked! I tried `Expression.Convert` the same way you did before, I only had `typeof(object)` and `parameterType` swapped.

Answer (score 5):

This is my way, it's working fine.

But i dont know it's performance.

```
    public static Func<object, object> GenerateGetterFunc(this PropertyInfo pi)
    {
        //p=> ((pi.DeclaringType)p).<pi>

        var expParamPo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
        var expParamPc = Expression.Convert(expParamPo,pi.DeclaringType);

        var expMma = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                expParamPc
                , pi
            );

        var expMmac = Expression.Convert(expMma, typeof(object));

        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(expMmac, expParamPo);

        return exp.Compile();
    }

    public static Action<object, object> GenerateSetterAction(this PropertyInfo pi)
    {
        //p=> ((pi.DeclaringType)p).<pi>=(pi.PropertyType)v

        var expParamPo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
        var expParamPc = Expression.Convert(expParamPo,pi.DeclaringType);

        var expParamV = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "v");
        var expParamVc = Expression.Convert(expParamV, pi.PropertyType);

        var expMma = Expression.Call(
                expParamPc
                , pi.GetSetMethod()
                , expParamVc
            );

        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(expMma, expParamPo, expParamV);

        return exp.Compile();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a convert method like `Convert.ChangeType`. The type of property is bool. But the return type of GetSetter methos is object. So you should convert property type that is bool in expression to object.

```
    public static Action<T, object> GetSetter<T>(T obj, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression targetExpr = Expression.Parameter(obj.GetType(), "Target");
        MemberExpression propExpr = Expression.Property(targetExpr, propertyName);
        ParameterExpression valueExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
        MethodCallExpression convertExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Convert), "ChangeType", null, valueExpr, Expression.Constant(propExpr.Type));
        UnaryExpression valueCast = Expression.Convert(convertExpr, propExpr.Type);
        BinaryExpression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(propExpr, valueCast);
        return Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(assignExpr, targetExpr, valueExpr).Compile();
    }

    private static Func<T, object> GetGetter<T>(T obj, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(obj.GetType(), "x");
        MemberExpression expression = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
        UnaryExpression conversion = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, arg).Compile();
    }
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://rextester.com/RWEU3198)

**EDIT:**

```
public class Foo
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Tuple<Func<Foo, object>, Action<Foo, object>>> dataProperties = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Func<Foo, object>, Action<Foo, object>>>();

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public string Data3 { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods: public

    public void BuildDataProperties()
    {
        foreach (
            var keyValuePair in
                GetType()
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Data"))
                    .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<Func<Foo, object>, Action<Foo, object>>>(p.Name, Tuple.Create(GetGetter(this, p.Name), GetSetter(this, p.Name))))) {
                        dataProperties.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
                    }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods: private

    private Func<T, object> GetGetter<T>(T obj, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(obj.GetType(), "x");
        MemberExpression expression = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
        UnaryExpression conversion = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, arg).Compile();
    }

    private Action<T, object> GetSetter<T>(T obj, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression targetExpr = Expression.Parameter(obj.GetType(), "Target");
        MemberExpression propExpr = Expression.Property(targetExpr, propertyName);
        ParameterExpression valueExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
        MethodCallExpression convertExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Convert), "ChangeType", null, valueExpr, Expression.Constant(propExpr.Type));
        UnaryExpression valueCast = Expression.Convert(convertExpr, propExpr.Type);
        BinaryExpression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(propExpr, valueCast);
        return Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(assignExpr, targetExpr, valueExpr).Compile();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can get a value from dictionary like below :

```
        var t = new Foo { ID = 1, Name = "Bla", Data1 = "dadsa"};
        t.BuildDataProperties();
        var value = t.dataProperties.First().Value.Item1(t);
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://rextester.com/WLA7307)

Comment: Looks good, except that I do not want convert functionality but cast functionality. In your demo `s(t, true);` would work even though the property is of type `int`. It will silently convert `true` to `(int)1` It doesn't throw an `InvalidCastException` (wich it should in my scenario).

Comment: You're right. `Change.Convert` doesnt work for you. So you can make your change method like `Convert.ChangeType` and you can use it for this. I m not sure how to use safely cast in this, maybe you can ask a new question for this.